# Exchange 2003 email addresses

Tags: active-directory, email, exchange-2003

I have approximately 20 users within exchange 2003. I just added a new domain name within the Default Policy Properties under Recipient Policies to be added to every user account's email address. This process was successful. However, when the default domain name was added to each persons account, the user name was added incorrectly.

For example, say I have **Joe Shmoe** working for me. When the domain was added to his account the email address was constructed to read... **jshmoe@jps.net** I want the email address to read **joe.shmoe@jps.net**

Is there a fix within exchange that can change this default setting or do I have to manually change each persons address to read what I want it to?

Comment: Not sure how that is the accepted answer when it only links to a document (Read the FAQ for the site) and doesn't provide you a real answer.

Comment: I understand that users of this site are looking for direct answers, but this is why I accepted that as the answer, because the link stepped me through exactly what I needed in great detail.

Comment: The site is to BE the source of information, not link to it.  I gave you the exact format you should use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for: (How to customize the SMTP e-mail address generators through recipient policies) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285136

Answer (score 1):

You must configure the address policy in the format you want it to use:

- %g  = givenName.
- %s  = sn (Lastname).
- %4s = means first four letters of sn.
- %d  = displayname.
- %m = Exchange alias.

So you would want your policy's smtp address to look like:

```
%g.%s@jps.net
```